# Disable ripple effect on vuetify components globally

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

I'm using `vuetify` on my application. The design team create a flat design and I want to change the theme of `vuetify` to match with mockups

I try to find an option to disable ripple effect easily all over the application but it doesn't exist.

I try to create a component extension to avoid repeating `:ripple="false"`on each component I use.

I'll take a button component as an example.

```
<v-btn :ripple="false">My Button</v-btn>
```

each button on my application need to have `ripple=false`
My aim is to create a component like this

```
<my-button>My Button</my-button>
```

I try to extend `v-btn` in another component like this.

```
<template>
    <v-btn v-bind="options" :ripple="false"></v-btn>
</template>

<script>
  import { VBtn } from 'vuetify';

  export default {
  name: 'MyButton',
  extend: VBtn,
  computed: {
    options() {
      return this.props;
    },
  },

};

</script>

<style scoped>
```

I try this way to avoid copy/paste all the props of `v-btn`.

All solutions that I've tried failed.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can modify Vue.js components globally even after they've been registered.
In this case, you can simply do this :

```js
const VBtn = Vue.component('VBtn')
VBtn.options.props.ripple.default = false
```

You can add that in your `vuetify.js` file before the `export default new Vuetify (...)` for instance.

- Tested with Vuetify 2.1.14

Comment: In my case, I was unable to utilize Vuetify's sass variable overrides, and this works great. Another note, is this works for other components too, e.g. VCheckbox, VChip, etc.

Comment: How you do this in typescript?

Comment: this doesnt work and shows console log error Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'options' of undefined

Answer (score 7):

You can set the complete container to not visible.

```
.v-ripple__container {
    display:none !important;
}
```

Comment: Good solution for a limited scope application! Thanks, Peter!

Answer (score 4):

According to [Vuetify documentation](https://v15.vuetifyjs.com/en/framework/theme#modifying-stylus-variables) you can modify the Stylus variables - so you can try to redefine these to your taste, e.g. by setting them to `none`:

```
$ripple-animation-transition-in := transform .25s $transition.fast-out-slow-in, opacity .1s $transition.fast-out-slow-in
$ripple-animation-transition-out := opacity .3s $transition.fast-out-slow-in
$ripple-animation-visible-opacity := .15
```

Answer (score 3):

Override ripple directive with global mixin in main.js

```
let overrideRipple = {
 directives:{
   ripple:{
     inserted: ()=> {
      console.log("Ripple overrided")
     }
   }
 }
}
Vue.mixin(overrideRipple);
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a class to the button and use CSS..

```
<v-btn class="custom-btn">Button</v-btn>

.custom-btn:deep(.v-btn__overlay) {
   display: none;
}
.custom-btn:deep(.v-btn__underlay) {
   display: none;
}
.custom-btn:deep(.v-ripple__container) {
   display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

On Vuetify 3.3.22 prop defaults accept component key references to apply style changes based on component hierarchy. See more in the [documentation](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/features/aliasing/#virtual-component-defaults)

Example:

```
import { createVuetify } from 'vuetify'
import { VBtn } from 'vuetify/components/VBtn'

export default createVuetify({
  defaults: {
    VBtn: {
      ripple: false,
    },
  },
})
```

Answer (score -3):

With the release of Vuetify 2.0 you can actually just turn off ripples globally by modifying your `vuetify.js` file like so.

```
export default new Vuetify({
  global: {
    ripples: false
  },
  icons: {
    iconfont: 'mdi',
  },
});
```

Comment: v.2.1.1 also not working... So when did this work? Why is this upvoted? Can someone confirm? Or provide source to docs which says this should work? I downvoted because apparently there is nothing official which implies this should work, thus answer is incorrect. Maybe in future versions.

Comment: @Traxo Only scheduled in v2.3 Release (Orion): Vuetify components will be pre-configurable through framework wide defaults. This will allow you to set global settings such as no-ripples or all inputs are of outlined type and even set all cards to become tiles.